# How to prevent the display in the logs of error when using angular httpClient.get?

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient, http-status-code-401

I've the following method:

```
  retrieveAccessToken() {
    this.httpClient
      .get(environment.backendUrl + 'accounts/refresh-token')
      .subscribe({
        next: (response) => {
          this.handleLogginResponse(response);
        },
        error: (err) => {
          console.log(`Ohoh, error while retriving refresh token`, err);
        },
      });
  }
```

It works fine. This method is used to retrieve the access token based on the HttpOnly token stored in the cookies. Since it's an HttpOnly cookie, I've no way of knowing if there is a token and if it's valid. So when the application, it requests the server, and the server will:

1. Return the access token(and a refreshed refresh-token) if it's valid
2. return a 401 unauthorized error if it's not valid.

The method work, but currently, I get anway in the error logs of the browser, the error:
[image]

My question is: How do I prevent the display of the error in this case? I don't want to use an interceptor that catch all, since it's only for this case.

Comment: did you solve it? Share your solution, please tag me after you share

Answer (score 0):

You can use [catchError](https://indepth.dev/reference/rxjs/operators/catch-error) operator to catch any errors and then return an [EMPTY](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/const/EMPTY) observable to suppress the error!

```js
retrieveAccessToken() {
  this.httpClient
    .get(environment.backendUrl + 'accounts/refresh-token')
    .pipe(
      catchError(error => EMPTY)
    )
    .subscribe({
      next: (response) => {
        this.handleLogginResponse(response);
      }
    });
}
```

Comment: thanks! I'm curious, why my code doesn't work? Shouldn't the error handler I indicate in the subscribe be called?

Comment: Observer has 3 functions - `next`, `error`, `complete`. When observers error out, it triggers `error`. Since the observer has errored out, that means your original http request observable has been completed. And since it is completed you have no power to control or override its behavior, thus it will print stuff in console. Whereas with `catchError` you replace the errored observable with the new (`EMPTY` in this case) observable and thus can override the behavior in way you like!

Comment: I just had the time to add the pipe(catchError(error=>EMPTY)) before the subscribe. But I still do get the error in the console logs. any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

You could add in the devMode logic to your console log:

```
      retrieveAccessToken() {
        this.httpClient
          .get(environment.backendUrl + 'accounts/refresh-token')
          .subscribe({
            next: (response) => {
              this.handleLogginResponse(response);
            },
            error: (err) => {
              if (isDevMode()) {
              console.log(`Ohoh, error while retriving refresh token`, err);
              }
            },
          });
      }
```

Comment: The log that is appearing is logged by the "httpClient", not by me

Answer (score 0):

#### Option 1

Even though you said you don't want to, your best bet is to implement a [HttpInterceptor](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpInterceptor) if you'd like to handle HTTP errors in general:

create the interceptor

```
@Injectable()
export class CustomErrorHttpInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return next.handle(req).pipe(
      catchError((err) => {
        if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse && !environment.production) {
          // <-- at this point you can check the err object and do something else if you'd like
          if (err.status == 401){
            console.log(`Ohoh, unauthorized`, err);
          } else {
            console.log(`Ohoh, http error`, err);  
          }
        }
        return throwError(err);
      })
    );
  }
}
```

and provide the interceptor in your app's main module

```
@NgModule({
providers: [
{ provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: AuthInterceptor, multi: true },
...
```

This should display the error in console when in dev mode, but not in production mode

#### Option 2

if your intention is really to handle it only at that servicecall, you should use a more usual rxjs pattern, as per [angular docs](https://angular.io/guide/http#handling-request-errors), this will keep you out of the trouble other patterns can get you into. Btw, there is nothing wrong with your code to handle this specific error, it is only missing a condition to not write the error to the console when necessary.

You should also instead of subscribing at the service, return the http client's observable:

```
retrieveAccessToken() {
  return this.httpClient.get(environment.backendUrl + 'accounts/refresh-token').pipe(
    catchError((err) => {
       if(!environment.production) 
          console.log(`Ohoh, error while retrieving refresh token`, err);

      // re-throw the error otherwise you would have to handle an "incorrect" non-error response when subscribing to the service
      return throwError(err);
    })
  );
}
```

Then when you use it from your component, that's when you subscribe:

```
componentFunction() {
  this.yourService.retrieveAccessToken().subscribe(() => {
    // do something if necessary
  })
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I think there is a small misunderstanding. It's not the console.log that I've on my code that I don't want to display(this one is easy to remove), there is an error that get displayed, event I never re-throw the error. This cannot be called inside my component, it's called by a RXJS timer(that gets started by a component)

Comment: You could use what I proposed above from the timer callback function the same way as from a component function. I though you console msg was simply representing something else you are doing. Where exactly can you view the "error that get displayed" ? The best way to handle http errors it via interceptor, in that you can view what url was called, the error code and msg + any other info the http error has.

Comment: Hello, it's in the console, displayed as error, there is one screenshot in the original question showing it. I get the chance to "catch" it and my code work, its just that the error still appears and we would like to avoid having console error in an expected behavior.